# MATLAB random number generate with loop problem

Tags: matlab

I just wanted to do a simple loop, which in a random number generation, if it gets 1, it exits the loop and also prints out how many steps it exited. The code doesn't work for some reason. Could you help me?

Thanks!

```
for n=1:5            
   app.lepesszam = 0;
   while app.i~=1
      app.i = 0;
      app.i = round(rand(1,1));
      app.lepesszam = app.lepesszam + 1;
   end
disp(app.lepesszam);
end
```

Answer (score -1):

I realized what the problem was.

```
...            
   app.lepesszam = 0;
   app.i = 0;
   while app.i~=1
      app.i = round(rand(1,1));
...
```

so it already works.

have a nice day.

Comment: I don’t see how this could make a difference.

Comment: For n=1 there is no difference but for n=2 to 5, it would not enter the while loop (with the above change, it will)